# SurfaceView hiding automatically

Tags: android

I am having a glview and a surface view. What i have done is that i have created a relative layout and add both views on that relative layout. Everything is working fine. My glview is at back and my surfaceview is at front.

But when i press home button and come back to my activity surface view automatically go at the back. Problem occurs only when i press home button.

I have tried several things but surfaceview is not coming at front.
Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution my self. Instead of adding everything into a single relative layout i have setcontentview(glview) to glview it will allow my glview to display on complete screen.

Everything else I have added to a relative layout and then addcontentview to my relative layout with transparent background. This allowed my relative layout to be always on front and my surfaceview which is on the same relative layout to be on front.